# ANTLR mismatched input 'NUM' expecting {.... , 'NUM'}

Tags: java, grammar, antlr4

I have a problem with ANTLR4 when trying to parse a file. It worked in the first place, but after adding the following to my grammar i get an error (see below):

```
TYPE_NUM: 'NUM';

mismatched input 'NUM' expecting {'LOAD', '\n', 'HEAR', 'NUM', 'STRING', 'COORD', 'BOOL', 'VOID', 'LIST'}
```

The 'NUM' keyword in my language is in the following rule:

```
typePrefix: type=('NUM' | 'BOOL' | 'STRING' | 'COORD' | 'LIST');
```

I also have the same problems with all the rest of my typePrefixes, but I'm guessing it's the same solution for all of them.

I have tried to replace all the options of the typePrefix rule with TYPE_NUM, TYPE_BOOL and so forth, but that did not seem to work.

**EDIT:**
By request in the comments I've posted the part of my grammar, where I use 'NUM':

```
prog
    :   roboDcl loads roboBodyDcl;
loads
    :   recursion=loads 'LOAD' '(' load_id=StringLit ')' '\n' 
    |   //lambda
    ;
memberDcl
    :   dcl=fieldDcl
    |   met_dcl=methodDcl
    |   '\n'
    ;
roboDcl
    :   id=Identifier':''\n'
    ;
roboBodyDcl
    :   recursion=roboBodyDcl dcl=memberDcl
    |   dcl=memberDcl   
    ;
fieldDcl
    :   t=typePrefix dcl_list=variableDclList '\n';
typePrefix
    :   type=('NUM' | 'BOOL' | 'STRING' | 'COORD' | 'LIST');
variableDclList
    :   single=variableDcl
    |   list=variableDclList ',' single=variableDcl
    ;
variableDcl
    :   var_init=variableInitializer
    |   id=Identifier '=' list_init=listInitializer
    ;
variableInitializer 
    :   expr=assignmentExpression
    ;
TYPE_NUM: 'NUM';
TYPE_STRING: 'STRING';
TYPE_COORD: 'COORD';
TYPE_BOOL: 'BOOL';
TYPE_VOID: 'VOID';
TYPE_LIST: 'LIST';
```

And as said before I have tried to replace the typePrefix rule with the following:

```
typePrefix
    :    type=(TYPE_NUM | TYPE_BOOL | TYPE_STRING | TYPE_COORD | TYPE_LIST);
```

I hope this will suffice and thanks in advance!

Comment: Post more information please, whole grammar if possible. Do I understand it correctly, that you have specified 'NUM' literal twice? Once as TYPE_NUM and then in typePrefix?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes it is correct that it's specified twice, but as I wrote, it doesn't change anything if I replace 'NUM' in typePrefix with TYPE_NUM.

The grammar is to long to be posted, but I will provide the declaration-part, which will hopefully suffice:\n
`fieldDcl
 : t=typePrefix dcl_list=variableDclList '\n';

variableDclList
 : single=variableDcl
 | list=variableDclList ',' single=variableDcl
 ;
variableDcl
 : var_init=variableInitializer
 ;
variableInitializer 
 : expr=assignmentExpression
 ;`

Comment: You say it's too long to be posted, but added it in the comment, which is hard to read. Please edit your question. If it's really that long, you can put in github/dropbox whatever and share the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and will try to provide an explanation in-case someone ends up in the same situation.

As stated "The Definitive Antlr 4 Reference" ANTLR resolves ambiguities in the lexer rules by choosing the rule defined first. And states *"That means your ID rule should be defined after all of your keyword rules..."*

In my case I had defined my grammar in the following manner:

```
fragment NameStartChar
    :       'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z';
fragment NameChar
    :       NameStartChar
    |       Num
    |       '_'
    ;
fragment Num
    :       '0'..'9';
Identifier
    :   NameStartChar NameChar*;
TYPE_NUM: 'NUM';
```

This ended up matching all of my keywords 'NUM', 'BOOL' and so forth.

**The solution was therefore to define the Identifier rule as the last of the lexer rules.** An example can be seen below:

```
fragment NameStartChar
    :       'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z';
fragment NameChar
    :       NameStartChar
    |       Num
    |       '_'
    ;
fragment Num
    :       '0'..'9';
TYPE_NUM: 'NUM';
//All other keyword definitions ('BOOL', 'STRING' and so alike)
Identifier
    :   NameStartChar NameChar*
```